# ListView MouseClick Event for URL

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

In column 3 I have link and I want to create ListView MouseClick Event for show web-site from  link in browser. I wrote this:

```
private void listView1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
     try
     {
         string linkOn = "linkto:" +                                       
         listView1.SelectedItems[id.Text].SubItems[linkOnTheme.Index].Text;
         System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(linkOn);
     }    
     catch (Win32Exception ex)
     {
         MessageBox.Show("An error has occured: " + ex.Message);
     }
}
```

but it work only for 1st column. Where I take a mistake?

Comment: How does it not work? Is the right item selected? Do you enter the Mouseclick?

Comment: Mouseclick must work only with column Link. By the way, It work for column ID, what call error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `MouseClick` and `Click` event of the `ListView` fire only on the (main) Item, not on any subitems.

So you must use other events and do a `HitTest` there:

The following code can either go into the `MouseDown` or in the `MouseUp` event:

```
    Point mousePos = listView1.PointToClient( Control.MousePosition );
    ListViewHitTestInfo htInfo = listView1.HitTest(mousePos);

    if (htInfo.Item == null) return;

    int itemIndex = htInfo.Item.Index;
    int subItemIndex = htInfo.Item.SubItems.IndexOf(htInfo.SubItem);

    if (subItemIndex == yourLinkColumnIndex)
    {
        try
        {
            string linkOn = "linkto:" +  htInfo.Item.SubItems[subItemIndex].Text;
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(linkOn);
        } catch (Win32Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("An error has occured: " + ex.Message);
        }

    }
```