# how to draw an icon button to a listview(winform)

Tags: c#, winforms

i want to draw an icon which can trigger a click event in detail view and large icon view.

```
private void ls_DrawSubItem(object sender, DrawListViewSubItemEventArgs e)
{
        if (e.ColumnIndex == ls.Columns.Count - 1)
        {
            e.DrawBackground();

            Rectangle imageRect = new Rectangle(e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y, e.Bounds.Height, e.Bounds.Height);
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(SystemIcons.Information.ToBitmap(), imageRect);

        }
        else
        {
            e.DrawDefault = true;
        }
    }
```

i use this to draw an icon, but how to give it a click event.

Comment: Things yu draw do not have an event model. You need to catch a mousedown or MouseCick and test if you have hit the image. The test will have to be done wrt the mode. Also watch out for scrolling!

Comment: thanks. then how to catch the mousedown?

Comment: ListView.MouseDown? As any other event. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27635166/listview-mouseclick-event-for-url/27639187#27639187) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32959874/listview-large-icon-right-click-to-open-contextmenustrip/32966057#32966057) for a few notes..

Comment: how do i know, if i cilck the icon i draw, when mousedown?

Comment: Have a look at the 2nd example!!